# Show and Hide using hasClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make `button` that show some stuff and then when its clicked again it hide that stuff. I have two buttons (`.BB11` and `.BB12`). Clicked button take `.OnBotMenu` class to change its apperance. `#Cont11` is the stuff i show. .Showing class makes that stuff visible.

```
$(".BB11").click(function(){

    if $(this).hasClass(".OnBotMenu") {

        $(".Showing").fadeOut(500);

    }

    else {

        $(".BB11").addClass(".OnBotMenu");
        $(".BB12").removeClass(".OnBotMenu");
        $("#Cont11").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#Cont11").addClass(".Showing");

    }
});
```

Comment: `If ($(".bb11").hasClass ("OnBotMenu")){...}`

Comment: As described by @SebastianKrysiak you don't need to use dot with class name in built class functions like `hasClass` `addClass` etc

Comment: You need to wrap your condition in parenthesis, you should also replace `$('.BB11')` with `$(this)` inside your click handler function.

Comment: the problem is that it shuts down my other scripts.

Comment: @Qriyo: Check your browser console.  It's telling you about your syntax error.  (So are the comments above.)

Comment: Thank you guys for fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Working code:

```
$(".BB11").click(function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass("OnBotMenu")) {

        $(".Showing").fadeOut(500);
        $(this).removeClass("OnBotMenu");

    }

    else {

        $(".Showing").fadeOut(500);
        $(".BB11").addClass("OnBotMenu");
        $(".BB12").removeClass("OnBotMenu");
        $("#Cont11").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#Cont11").addClass("Showing");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");` for showing and hiding elements with fade effect.

Example is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadetoggle)

Comment: cant apply this solution here. I have two buttons that shows diferent things  artenatly.